# How to make akonadi stop caching e-mails?

Tags: kmail

The problem: `~/.local/share/akonadi` folder takes as much space as `~/.local/share/local-mail`, which eats quite a few GB of space. Since [`akonadi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akonadi) just caches e-mails, how can it be configured so that it will skip this caching, thus, releasing a few GB of data back to the user?

The setup: i'm using kmail to retrieve e-mails from several pop accounts to local folders (`~/.local/share/local-mail`). akonadi on the other hand caches the e-mails from the local folder under `~/.local/share/akonadi`, which i don't really want, hence the problem

Comment: Should you not just remove the emails from ~/.local/share/local-mail` or tell the application that stores data there not do so? `akonadi` is a storage service so why ask it not to do what it is intended to do?

Comment: @Anthon why would someone want to delete the content of local mail folders? if that folder is deleted, then all local e-mails are lost, and thus akonadi won't attempt caching non existent e-mails. the purpose of akonadi is not entirely clear to me. i dont need caching of e-mails into a mysql database - a maildir is just fine. 10 gb of local e-mails results in additional 10 gb of wasted space. i need to trick akonadi into not caching what it's supposed to cache. hence, my question.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear about whether the stuff under `akonadi` came from some other server and was then cached under `local-mail` by some mail reader program or as you now describe the other way around. You should improve your question with the description of Which program stores it under `local-mail` and how you configured  akonadi to pick it up from there. As it is your comment indicates that all these emails are generated locally and stored under `local-mail`. Don't comment, just improve the question with relevant info ( we know you think you are wasting space).

Comment: And please read at least the [tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) under the help menu, so you know the basics of how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

Here is the solution for those who may face similar issues:

1. stop akonadi and kmail
2. remove the content of ~/.local/share/akonadi/file_db_data
3. move all e-mail from of ~/.local/share/.local-mail.directory to a temp_directory
4. move all e-mail from ~/.local/share/local-mail to the same temp_directory
5. restart kmail and import all e-mails while removing the duplicates.